# How to Ignore checkstyle javadoc warning for a method with a specific annotation

Tags: java, annotations, checkstyle

Checkstyle warns when I have a public method without javadoc, which is nice! When I override a public method I don't get the warning because the javadoc is already available in the parent class for the method.

Now I have an other annotation for my method for example `@MyEvent`. Now I do get the warning but don't want it because the annotation says enough. Can I exclude warnings for methods with a specific annotation?

There are some solutions that involve adding stuff to my code like `@SuppressWarnings` or comments like `// CHECKSTYLE.OFF` but this does not make my code nicer, i could instead just add the javadoc. So I'm looking for a configuration level solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The allowedAnnotations property of JavadocMethod module defines which annoted methods are skipped/ignored for javadoc check.
The given example uses Checkstyle v8.8 .

```
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test, Before, BeforeClass"/>
    </module>
  </module>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I exclude warnings for methods with a specific annotation?

You can suppress warnings by using one specific annotation (`@SuppressWarnings`), but other annotations can not be used to that effect (such as `@MyEvent`).

At least not out of the box. If you are willing to do some programming, you can develop your own [custom filter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingfilters.html) that does what you need.

Comment: Programming it is then. I'll post the code here if I ever decide to do this :) thanks!