# Exclude annotated methods from checkstyle-check

Tags: android, checkstyle

In an Android-project I'm trying to integrate checkstyle.
As I'm using [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations), a few methods have to be declared like this:

```
@Click(R.id.togglePlay)
protected final void doPauseResume() {
}
```

They need to be protected in order for the generated class to be able to call them.
How could I teach checkstyle disable a few warnings, based on the `@Click` annotation, (or more broadly, based on a annotation in the `org.androidannotations.annotations` package)?

The class has other `protected` methods, which I want to keep being checked, of course.

Do I need to implement a [Filter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingfilters.html)?

Comment: I am wondering, what check do you use for this? `VisibilityModifier` is only for fields, i think.

Comment: @WonderCsabo don't know yet, but I'm tempted to write a Filter and let it remove the `AuditEvent`s that are relevant to AA.

Comment: VisibilityModifier has ignoreAnnotationCanonicalNames parameter which can be used for this purpose without a Filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Ignore checkstyle javadoc warning for a method with a specific annotation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26120003/1005481)